# Facebook messenger analysis using jupyter Notebook

Tags: pandas, nlp, nltk, tokenize

I downloaded Facebook messenger data and I'm trying to analyze it.
So my goal is to know the number of occurrences of a word in all messages.
I converted the JSON file to a pandas Dataframe, and I have a column that contains all the messages.
I converted the messages column to a list and I tried to use NLTK to count the words.

```
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize
from nltk.probability import FreqDist

mylist = df['content'].tolist()
tok_words = [word_tokenize(i) for i in mylist]
```

but the problem is when I tried  to use FreqDist it shows an error "TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'"

```
fdist = FreqDist(tok_words)
fdist.most_common(5)
```

and when tried this it works for me

```
fdist = FreqDist(tok_words[0])
fdist.most_common(5)
```

I want to use FreqDist to all of the list not only to the first index.

Comment: Can you provide an example dataframe with expected results?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
fdist = FreqDist()
for words in tok_words:
    fdist.update(FreqDist(words))
fdist.most_common(5)
```